# What does "Routing and Remote Access Service" do in this usecase?

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-11

For Windows 11, Microsoft released a cumulative update in may with number KB5026372.
This update is notorious to brick VPN connections in such way that the speed is severely reduced to basically render VPN useless. The update does other (bad) things too and is massive.

So far, the recommended resolution was to uninstall this update. Microsoft will keep pushing this update, so every once in a while, the update needed to be uninstalled again to fix VPN once more.

Recently I found out that if you change the service Routing and Remote Access from disabled to automatic, and you then create a VPN connection, the VPN is not slowed down and actually usable.

This was especially needed because we found out that on more computers now the update could no longer be uninstalled, which until this point had resulted in reinstalling windows.

I'm still not that happy with this new fix because I fail to see why this works.

So the question is: What does the service Routing and Remote Access do that would allow this to work, and more importantly, is this a fix I can continue to use, or does this has side effects that should make me reconsider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn614140(v=ws.11))
is supposed to chiefly facilitate access to a VPN *server* from the client.
It's not supposed to take part in enabling a *client* to access a VPN.

Whatever glitch you have discovered, it's not a known solution.
If it negates the effects of the bug introduced by KB5026372,
this is just a coincidence and not an intentional feature.

You are in an unknown situation, since even the bug introduced by this KB
is not generally known, let alone how to mitigate it.

You may use it as a workaround, as long as it works for your users.
There is no guarantee that it will keep on working with future
updates of Windows.

The most you can do is signal the problem via the Feedback Hub, also
mentioning your workaround, then hope that the next update will
fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am not the one who discovered the workaround, unless you also count in that I found someone mentioning it by google, yes, then I discovered it. LOL.

Comment: I've accepted it as the update is no longer being pushed and we no longer needed to do this. I even think a new update was pushed that fixed things, but not sure. Anyway, by the lack of any better answer, and the lack of needing an answer, I'll mark this solved. Thanks for your answer.